# ASP.NET Convert Invalid String to Null

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, validation, data-binding

In my application I have `TextBox` in a `FormView` bound to a `LinqDataSource` like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("MyValue") %>' AutoPostBack="True" 
             ontextchanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged" />

protected void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFormView.UpdateItem(false);
}
```

This is inside an `UpdatePanel` so any change to the field is immediately persisted. Also, the value of `MyValue` is `decimal?`.  This works fine unless I enter any string which cannot be converted to decimal into the field.  In that case, the `UpdateItem` call throws:

> **LinqDataSourceValidationException** -
>   Failed to set one or more properties on type MyType.  asdf is not a valid value for Decimal.

I understand the problem, ASP.NET does not know how to convert from 'asdf' to decimal?. What I would like it to do is convert all these invalid values to null.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should handle the Updating event of the LinqDataSource on your page.  Do your check for invalid strings (use a TryParse method or something) and then continue with the base class update.

(Edit:  My intuition lines up with what's recommended [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourcevalidationexception.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with ASP, but in .net, couldn't you just do something along the lines of

```
protected void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Decimal d = null;
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

    if(!Decimal.TryParse(tb.Text, out d))
    {
            tb.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    MyFormView.UpdateItem(false);
}
```